# Об осложнённом предложении

Tags: синтаксис

Стеклющийся по паркету шлейф занимал много места.
Стелющийся по паркету, шлейф доставлял неудобства.
Шлейф, стелющийся по паркету, занимал много места.

Первое предложение среди приведенных - единственное неосложнённое? Об осложнении свидетельствуют только знаки выделения и разделения?

Answer (score 1):

Да, именно так.

> ОСЛОЖНЁННОЕ ПРЕДЛОЖЕ́НИЕ — простое предложение, в котором присутствуют
>   "осложняющие элементы", выражающие добавочное сообщение. Осложняющие
>   элементы подразделяются на два подтипа. Во-первых, к ним относятся
>   однородные  и обособленные чл. предложения; ср.: Я
>   купил хлеб и молоко; Геолог, он объездил всю страну, а во-вторых,
>   слова и словосоч., не являющиеся чл. предложения и не входящие в его
>   структуру: вводные и вставные конструкции, обращения и междометия;
>   ср.: Может быть, он дома; Летите, голуби, летите; Увы, все пропало!

https://humanities_dictionary.academic.ru/4451/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%91

Comment: Второе предложение  тоже не является осложненным — там просто лишняя запятая перед определяемым словом, просто ошибка.  _Стелющийся по паркету шлейф доставлял неудобства._

Comment: А разве "стелющийся по паркету" не объясняет прияину, по которой шлейф доставлял неудобства?

Comment: Так у Вас и в первом предложении "стелющийся по паркету" — только без запятой. (Исправьте: сте**к**лющийся.) В чем же разница? Запятая возможна только перед местоимением: _Стелющийся по паркету, он доставлял неудобства._

Comment: Римма, Вы неправы, второе предложение вполне может быть осложнённым, если автор  придаёт причастному обороту причинное значение: шлейф доставлял неудобства, потому что он стелился по паркету. В первом предложении фразовое ударение падает на сказуемое, а во втором на определение со значением причины - как автор произнесёт, так и поставит запятые.